# Azure Data Flow: Array to columns

Tags: azure-data-factory

In my data flow I have a column with an array and I need to map it to columns.
Here is an example of the data:

```
["title:mr","name:jon","surname:smith"]
[surname:jane"]
["title:mrs","surname:peters"]
["title:mr"]
```

and here is an example of the desired result:

[image]

what's the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the combination of derived column, rank and pivot transformations.

- Let's say I have the given sample data (array of strings) as a column `mycol`.

[image]

- Now, I have used `rank` transformation. I have given column name `id` for rank column and used `mycol` column for sort condition (ascending order). The result would be as shown below:

[image]

- Now I have used derived column to create a `new` column with dynamic expression as `unfold(mycol)`.

[image]

- For some reason this new column's type was not being rendered properly. So, I have used cast to make it complex type with complex type defination as `string[]`.
- I have created 2 new columns `key` and `value`. The dynamic contents are as follows:

```
key: split(new[1],':')[1]
value: split(new[1],':')[2]
```

[image]

- Now I have used `pivot` transformation. Here I have used group by on `id`, selected pivot column as `key` and selected pivoted columns as `max(value)` (since aggregate has to be used).

[image]

- The required result is obtained. The following is the entire dataflow JSON (The actual transformations start from rank as you already have the array column.)

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "csv1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "dest",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "rank1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "cast1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "pivot1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          mycol as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1",
                "source1 derive(mycol = split(replace(replace(replace(mycol,'[',''),']',''),'\"',''),',')) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "derivedColumn1 rank(asc(mycol, true),",
                "     output(id as long)) ~> rank1",
                "rank1 derive(new = unfold(mycol)) ~> derivedColumn2",
                "derivedColumn2 cast(output(",
                "          new as string[]",
                "     ),",
                "     errors: true) ~> cast1",
                "cast1 derive(key = split(new[1],':')[1],",
                "          value = split(new[1],':')[2]) ~> derivedColumn3",
                "derivedColumn3 pivot(groupBy(id),",
                "     pivotBy(key),",
                "     {} = max(value),",
                "     columnNaming: '$N$V',",
                "     lateral: true) ~> pivot1",
                "pivot1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     partitionFileNames:['op.csv'],",
                "     umask: 0022,",
                "     preCommands: [],",
                "     postCommands: [],",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     saveOrder: 1,",
                "     partitionBy('hash', 1)) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! this is working in data preview...however in debug I get the following error: Job failed due to reason: None.get. My dataset is around 200 million rows, so unrol+pivot maybe has performance issues? Was hoping for a string expression could work here

Comment: Pivot would be necessary as we are creating new columns from row values (title, surname and name). String manipulation might not help in getting desired results.